# Controller is after rename of solution not avaible

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have rename my main solution. My controllers are in another solution. The main solution has a dependencie on the rest-solution. All solution worked very well, but one is not avaible under the old route. I do not change the route of the controller.

Old route before renaming was `[Route("api/identity/user")]`. If i used it, i get only the errorpage.

Here's what I found out:

- If i changed it to another route like `[Route("api/identity/asdf")]` or `[Route("api/identity/user_old")]` the controller worked very well.
- Clean Solution and Restart Visual Studio don't help
- Change port of launchsettings don't help
- Moving file to another folder don't help
- Deletion bin folder from main-solution don't help
- i can access to old route (if it config) with postmen, but not with swagger or my blazor wasm frontend
- with Postmen i arrived my breakpoint, with swagger or blazor wasm i get nothing
- on all routes i get a log like: `Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET  https://localhost:44344/api/...`, but on my specific route it is different
- with postmen i get the log, but not with blazor wasm or swagger

I don't understand, where is the problem.

Edit 1: More Code
This not worked

```
    [Route("api/identity/user")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController :  CustomControllerBase<UserController>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;



        public UserController(IUserService userService, ILogger<UserController> logger) : base(logger)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Get User Details
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Status 200 OK</returns>
        [HttpGet()]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var users = await _userService.GetAllUsersAsync();
            return Ok(users);
        }
}
```

And this worked

```
    [Route("api/identity/users")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController :  CustomControllerBase<UserController>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;



        public UserController(IUserService userService, ILogger<UserController> logger) : base(logger)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }




        /// <summary>
        /// Get User Details
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Status 200 OK</returns>
        [HttpGet()]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var users = await _userService.GetAllUsersAsync();
            return Ok(users);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that in addition to the route [Route("api/identity/user")], any route can be accessed normally if you modify it? Can you provide the relevant code?

Comment: No. I can arrive every route. but not this [Route("api/identity/user")], if i use it. If I change the route to anything, it is accessible. It doesn't even matter what I change it to. Only the one route is not accessible.